# Ajax doesn't work when clicking on a link, why?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a function:

```
if (typeof history.pushState !== "undefined") {
        var historyCount = 0;
        $('.pytania a , .kontakt a , .ofirmie a , .cennik a').click(function(){
            var getlink = $(this).attr('href');
            $.ajax({url: getlink,success: function(data) {
                $('.container_right_wrapper').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 300, function(){
                $(this).html(data).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 300);
                $( ".pageicon img" ).remove();
                var image = $('.container_right_wrapper .attachment-post-thumbnail').prop('src') ;
                $('.pageicon').append('<img src="'+image+'"/>');
                $('.logo').prepend('<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>"></a>');
                });
            }
            });
            history.pushState(null, null, getlink);
            return false;
        });
        $('.projekty a').click(function(){
            var projekty = $(this).attr('href');
            $.ajax({url: projekty,success: function(data) {
                $('.container_right_wrapper').hide('slide', {direction: 'left',easing:'linear'}, 200, function(){
                $(this).html(data).show('slide', {direction: 'right',easing:'easeOutQuart'}, 200);
                carousel();
                $( ".pageicon img" ).remove();
                var image = $('.container_right_wrapper .attachment-post-thumbnail').prop('src') ;
                $('<img src="'+image+'"/>').appendTo('.pageicon');
                });
            }
            });
            history.pushState(null, null, projekty);
            return false;
        });
        $('.logo a').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var homepage = $(this).attr('href');
            $.ajax({url: homepage, success: function(data) {
                $('.container_right_wrapper').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 200, function(){
                $(this).html(data).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 200);
                $( ".pageicon img" ).remove();
                var image = $('.container_right_wrapper .attachment-post-thumbnail').prop('src');
                $('.pageicon').append('<img src="'+image+'"/>');
                slider();
                });
            }
            });
            history.pushState(null, null, homepage);
            return false;
        });
        window.onpopstate = function(){
            if(historyCount) {
                goTo(document.location);
            }
            historyCount = historyCount+1;
        };
    }
```

In the first part of it, when you click on a link (pytania a, kontakt a, etc) it goes, using ajax, to that page. It also creates link in .logo div (lint to hmepage to be exact). But when I click back on a created link it doesn't use ajax to go to homepage. I tried to use event.prevent default on click function (as you can see in third part of the function) but with no success, what am I missing?

Comment: show your html for <a> .. is the href set?

Comment: yes, it's been set, you can see it on [here](http://www.trzywu.pl/trzywu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use delegated event handlers and use `preventDefault` to prevent the default navigation:

```
$('.logo').on('click', 'a', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); /* ... */ });
```

Because at the time you first assign the handler to `.logo a` the element is nonexistent, so the handler is never actually assigned.

With delegated handlers, the handler gets assigned to `.logo`, which is present in the page from the beginning, but it only gets triggered when the event is bubbling up from the `a` element.

See the [documentation about delegated event handling](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Also note that in the string:

```
'<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>"></a>'
```

`<? ... ?>` will be left as it is, because php code won't be evaluated on the client side

Comment: I'm not worried about PHP code you mentioned, because it actually echoes my home page address. Your solution is great and it works perfectly. I'm reading about delegated events, it's interesting. Thank you.